# Problemas al generar código de barras

Tags: php, html, código-de-barras

Realizo un sistema de etiquetado, estoy trabajando con códigos de barras pero no consigo que se realice el mismo por medio del select  que tiene el  campo mod_cve, este se debe obtener el el

&size=40&codetype=Code128&print=true" />

Agradecería cualquier comentario o ayuda.

Saludos

```html
<td class="bajo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-16">
      <select style="border:none" class="form-control" name="mod_cve" id="mod_cve">
        <option value="0">-- Selecciona --</option>
        <?php

    $db = new MySQL();  
    $db->open();
    $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM cve ORDER BY name ASC");
    if ($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta)) {
        do {
    echo 
    '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[name].'</option>';
    }while($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta));
    }
                                        ?>
      </select>
      <img src="codigo_barras/barcode.php?text=<?php echo $_GET['mod_cve']; ?>&size=40&codetype=Code128&print=true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

[image: Imagen de formulario]

**barcode.php**

```html
<?php

/*
 *  Author  David S. Tufts
 *  Company davidscotttufts.com
 *    
 *  Date:   05/25/2003
 *  Usage:  <img src="/barcode.php?text=testing" alt="testing" />
 */

// For demonstration purposes, get pararameters that are passed in through $_GET or set to the default value
$filepath = (isset($_GET["filepath"])?$_GET["filepath"]:"");
$text = (isset($_GET["text"])?$_GET["text"]:"0");
$size = (isset($_GET["size"])?$_GET["size"]:"20");
$orientation = (isset($_GET["orientation"])?$_GET["orientation"]:"horizontal");
$code_type = (isset($_GET["codetype"])?$_GET["codetype"]:"code128");
$print = (isset($_GET["print"])&&$_GET["print"]=='true'?true:false);
$sizefactor = (isset($_GET["sizefactor"])?$_GET["sizefactor"]:"1");

// This function call can be copied into your project and can be made from anywhere in your code
barcode( $filepath, $text, $size, $orientation, $code_type, $print, $sizefactor );

function barcode( $filepath="", $text="0", $size="20", $orientation="horizontal", $code_type="code128", $print=false, $SizeFactor=1 ) {
    $code_string = "";
    // Translate the $text into barcode the correct $code_type
    if ( in_array(strtolower($code_type), array("code128", "code128b")) ) {
        $chksum = 104;
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","\`"=>"111422","a"=>"121124","b"=>"121421","c"=>"141122","d"=>"141221","e"=>"112214","f"=>"112412","g"=>"122114","h"=>"122411","i"=>"142112","j"=>"142211","k"=>"241211","l"=>"221114","m"=>"413111","n"=>"241112","o"=>"134111","p"=>"111242","q"=>"121142","r"=>"121241","s"=>"114212","t"=>"124112","u"=>"124211","v"=>"411212","w"=>"421112","x"=>"421211","y"=>"212141","z"=>"214121","{"=>"412121","|"=>"111143","}"=>"111341","~"=>"131141","DEL"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","FNC 4"=>"114131","CODE A"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

        $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code128a" ) {
        $chksum = 103;
        $text = strtoupper($text); // Code 128A doesn't support lower case
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","NUL"=>"111422","SOH"=>"121124","STX"=>"121421","ETX"=>"141122","EOT"=>"141221","ENQ"=>"112214","ACK"=>"112412","BEL"=>"122114","BS"=>"122411","HT"=>"142112","LF"=>"142211","VT"=>"241211","FF"=>"221114","CR"=>"413111","SO"=>"241112","SI"=>"134111","DLE"=>"111242","DC1"=>"121142","DC2"=>"121241","DC3"=>"114212","DC4"=>"124112","NAK"=>"124211","SYN"=>"411212","ETB"=>"421112","CAN"=>"421211","EM"=>"212141","SUB"=>"214121","ESC"=>"412121","FS"=>"111143","GS"=>"111341","RS"=>"131141","US"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","CODE B"=>"114131","FNC 4"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

        $code_string = "211412" . $code_string . "2331112";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code39" ) {
        $code_array = array("0"=>"111221211","1"=>"211211112","2"=>"112211112","3"=>"212211111","4"=>"111221112","5"=>"211221111","6"=>"112221111","7"=>"111211212","8"=>"211211211","9"=>"112211211","A"=>"211112112","B"=>"112112112","C"=>"212112111","D"=>"111122112","E"=>"211122111","F"=>"112122111","G"=>"111112212","H"=>"211112211","I"=>"112112211","J"=>"111122211","K"=>"211111122","L"=>"112111122","M"=>"212111121","N"=>"111121122","O"=>"211121121","P"=>"112121121","Q"=>"111111222","R"=>"211111221","S"=>"112111221","T"=>"111121221","U"=>"221111112","V"=>"122111112","W"=>"222111111","X"=>"121121112","Y"=>"221121111","Z"=>"122121111","-"=>"121111212","."=>"221111211"," "=>"122111211","$"=>"121212111","/"=>"121211121","+"=>"121112121","%"=>"111212121","*"=>"121121211");

        // Convert to uppercase
        $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

        for ( $X = 1; $X<=strlen($upper_text); $X++ ) {
            $code_string .= $code_array[substr( $upper_text, ($X-1), 1)] . "1";
        }

        $code_string = "1211212111" . $code_string . "121121211";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code25" ) {
        $code_array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
        $code_array2 = array("3-1-1-1-3","1-3-1-1-3","3-3-1-1-1","1-1-3-1-3","3-1-3-1-1","1-3-3-1-1","1-1-1-3-3","3-1-1-3-1","1-3-1-3-1","1-1-3-3-1");

        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            for ( $Y = 0; $Y < count($code_array1); $Y++ ) {
                if ( substr($text, ($X-1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y] )
                    $temp[$X] = $code_array2[$Y];
            }
        }

        for ( $X=1; $X<=strlen($text); $X+=2 ) {
            if ( isset($temp[$X]) && isset($temp[($X + 1)]) ) {
                $temp1 = explode( "-", $temp[$X] );
                $temp2 = explode( "-", $temp[($X + 1)] );
                for ( $Y = 0; $Y < count($temp1); $Y++ )
                    $code_string .= $temp1[$Y] . $temp2[$Y];
            }
        }

        $code_string = "1111" . $code_string . "311";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "codabar" ) {
        $code_array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","$",":","/",".","+","A","B","C","D");
        $code_array2 = array("1111221","1112112","2211111","1121121","2111121","1211112","1211211","1221111","2112111","1111122","1112211","1122111","2111212","2121112","2121211","1121212","1122121","1212112","1112122","1112221");

        // Convert to uppercase
        $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

        for ( $X = 1; $X<=strlen($upper_text); $X++ ) {
            for ( $Y = 0; $Y<count($code_array1); $Y++ ) {
                if ( substr($upper_text, ($X-1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y] )
                    $code_string .= $code_array2[$Y] . "1";
            }
        }
        $code_string = "11221211" . $code_string . "1122121";
    }

    // Pad the edges of the barcode
    $code_length = 20;
    if ($print) {
        $text_height = 30;
    } else {
        $text_height = 0;
    }
    
    for ( $i=1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++ ){
        $code_length = $code_length + (integer)(substr($code_string,($i-1),1));
        }

    if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" ) {
        $img_width = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
        $img_height = $size;
    } else {
        $img_width = $size;
        $img_height = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
    }

    $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height + $text_height);
    $black = imagecolorallocate ($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill( $image, 0, 0, $white );
    if ( $print ) {
        imagestring($image, 5, 31, $img_height, $text, $black );
    }

    $location = 10;
    for ( $position = 1 ; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++ ) {
        $cur_size = $location + ( substr($code_string, ($position-1), 1) );
        if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" )
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, $location*$SizeFactor, 0, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        else
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, 0, $location*$SizeFactor, $img_width, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        $location = $cur_size;
    }
    
    // Draw barcode to the screen or save in a file
    if ( $filepath=="" ) {
        header ('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    } else {
        imagepng($image,$filepath);
        imagedestroy($image);       
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Cambia tu `if(...) do{...}while;` por un simple `while(...){...}`.

Comment: Cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola @MRDev  en el img debo obtener el valor del campo  mod_cve  del Select que es el nombre de la clave para que se realice el código de barras.

Comment: @Carlos Pero agrega más detalles como que biblioteca usas para la creación de código, si quieres usar AJAX o con POST normal, todo lo necesario para que se te pueda apoyar

Comment: Has fijado en como estas creando tu url ```<?php echo mod_cve>&size```, si **mod_cve** debe ser el campo select quizás lo debes obtener via GET o POST ```echo $_POST['mod_cve'];```, luego tampoco veo la etiqueta de cierre de PHP, podría quedar así: ```<img src="codigo_barras/barcode.php?text=<?php echo $_POST['mod_cve']; ?>&size=40&codetype=Code128&print=true" />```. Y para que tu imagen coja el efecto dinámico, quizás deberías usar la función ```.on('change')``` de jQuery.

Comment: Para que la imagen del código de barra se refresque cuando se cambia el select, necesitas hacerlo a través de JavaScript, '$_GET' solo funcionará cuando la página carga la primera vez, o cuando se envie un formulario, pero en el código presentado no veo ninguna etiqueta <form>

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente le mandas al cliente la clave para que se la regrese al servidor y éste le devuelva  al cliente la imagen con el código de barras (CDB); en lugar de marear los datos puedes mandar el CDB desde un inicio.

Después de incluir el código de `barcode.php`, al procesar la consulta SQL, para cada clave se genera el respectivo CDB en formato base64 para agregarlo como un atributo personalizado `data-barcode` a cada opción; del lado del cliente, al cambiar la selección simplemente actualizar la imagen con CDB obtenido de la opción seleccionada.

```
<td class="bajo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-16">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function codigoDeBarras(e){
            let opt = document.querySelector('option[value="'+e.value+'"]');
            let imgCdb = document.getElementById('codigoDeBarras');
            imgCdb.src = 'data:image/png;base64, '+opt.getAttribute('data-barcode');
         }
      </script>
      <select style="border:none" class="form-control" name="mod_cve" id="mod_cve" onchange="codigoDeBarras(this)">
        <option value="0">-- Selecciona --</option>
          <?php
            include_once 'barcode.php'; // Modifica para tu ruta
            $db = new MySQL();  
            $db->open();
            $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM cve ORDER BY name ASC");
            while( $row = $db->fetch_array($consulta) ){
               barcode( $ruta = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'cdb'), $row['name']);
               echo sprintf( '<option value="%s" data-barcode="%s">%s</option>'
                           , $row['id']
                           , base64_encode(file_get_contents($ruta))
                           , $row['name']
                           );
            }
          ?>
      </select>
      <img id="codigoDeBarras" />
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Similarmente, la alternativa de usar una fuente:

```
<td class="bajo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-16">
      <style>
         @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+128+Text&display=swap');
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function codigoDeBarras(e){
            let opt = document.querySelector('option[value="'+e.value+'"]');
            let cdb = document.getElementById('cdb');
            cdb.innerText = opt.getAttribute('data-barcode');
         }
      </script>

      <select style="border:none" class="form-control" name="mod_cve" id="mod_cve" onchange="codigoDeBarras(this)">
        <option value="0">-- Selecciona --</option>
          <?php
            $db = new MySQL();  
            $db->open();
            $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM cve ORDER BY name ASC");
            function encode128A($str){
                $sum = 104;
                foreach( str_split($str) as $i => $x )
                   $sum += ++$i * (ord($x)-32);
                return utf8_encode( chr(203).$str.chr($sum%103+31).chr(206) );
            }
            while( $row = $db->fetch_array($consulta) ){
               echo sprintf( '<option value="%s" data-barcode="%s">%s</option>'
                           , $row['id']
                           , encode128A($row['name'])
                           , $row['name']
                           );
            }
          ?>
      </select>
      <p id="cdb" style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128 Text'; font-size: 45px; margin: 15px;"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Para usar la fuente necesitas codificar la cadena; en PHP puedes usar [esta función](http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar/code128_PHP.txt). A manera de prueba de concepto dejo un fragmento de código con javascript que genera códigos de un subconjunto del tipo B, sólo con dígitos y letras mayúsculas.

```js
function codigoDeBarras(e){
    let opt = document.querySelector('option[value="'+e.value+'"]');
    let sum = 104;
    for( var i=0; i<opt.text.length; i++ )
       sum += (i+1) * (opt.text.charCodeAt(i)-32);
    let barcode = String.fromCharCode(203)+opt.text+String.fromCharCode(sum%103+31,206);
    let cdb = document.getElementById('cdb');
    cdb.innerText = barcode;
 }
```

```html
<td class="bajo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-16">
      <style>
         @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+128+Text&display=swap');
      </style>
      <select style="border:none" class="form-control" name="mod_cve" id="mod_cve" onchange="codigoDeBarras(this)">
        <option value="0">-- Selecciona --</option>
        <option value="1">S473438</option>
        <option value="3">S473439</option>
      </select>
      <p id="cdb" style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128 Text'; font-size: 45px; margin: 15px;"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Hola @Sal, gracias por tus comentarios la segunda opción es la que aparentemente me funciona ya  que el código de barras lo muestra muy pequeño también le coloque la etiqueta size para aumentar tamaño pero no realiza nada y quiero que se muestre el texto que contiene el codigo con un print="true" pero no lo realiza.

Comment: lo coloque en esta linea   <p id="cdb" style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128'" size="40" print="true"/>

Comment: Es `font-size` y faltaría la unidad de medida. Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: ya me genera el código de barras, pero al escanearlo me arroja otro texto totalmente diferente al mod_cve; es decir tendría que escanear el código que esta arriba :(

Comment: Cierto @Carlos, el detalle de usar la fuente es que necesita codificarse; actualicé la respuesta para incluir una codificación muy básica y con cambios a la fuente para que muestre es texto.

Comment: actualice el código que me proporcionas pero ahora de plano ya no genera ningún código de barras

Comment: Debe funcionar @Carlos, hice varios cambios pequeños, revisa línea por línea o copia todo el código nuevamente.

Comment: ya copie todo el código y lo remplace pero continua igual, no se se pueda trasladar a una conexión remota para que puedas visualizar mi código.

Answer (score 0):

Encuentro varios problemas en tu codigo, te los comento:

1º En esta linea de tu codigo:

```
<img src="codigo_barras/barcode.php?text=<?php echo mod_cve>&size=40&codetype=Code128&print=true" />
```

abres el tag de php (`<?php`), pero no lo cierras.

2º En la misma linea:

```
  <img src="codigo_barras/barcode.php?text=<?php echo mod_cve>&size=40&codetype=Code128&print=true" />
```

usas `echo mod_cve`, pero `mod_cve` no esta definido en ningún lado, y le falta el `$`

Por ultimo, si quieres hacer códigos de barras, bájate una fuente dedicada a ello, y escribe tu codigo de barras con esa fuente, será mas fácil de manejar.

En el codigo que has agregado, que es como creas el codigo de barras, al final dice:

```
if ( $filepath=="" ) {
        header ('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    } else {
        imagepng($image,$filepath);
        imagedestroy($image);       
    }
```

Tu no indicas el nada para la variable `$filepath`, por lo tanto se printa en pantalla el código de barras.
La conclusión es que no puedes usar `barcode.php` como lo usas o de la forma que lo usas, por que devuelve o fichero o un print de la imagen en el navegador y por lo tanto no puedes asignarlo al atributo `src` del `img`.

Si puedes modificar el archivo `php`, yo modificaría para que me devuelva un base64, que se puede poner directamente en el `src` del `img`

Comment: Hola @Srsole, tienes toda la razón no había cerrado el php, por otro lado el mod_cve lo obtengo por medio de ajax en este caso solo es obtenerlo por el mod_cve. Ocupo una libreria para generar barcorde solo no puedo obtener el campo mod_cve

Comment: en el src hago un llamado al barcorde.php que se encarga de generar el código de barras.

Comment: @Carlos en cualquier caso, tu select, que es '*' no haces nada con la varible mod_cve

Comment: @Carlos estaria bien que pusieras en PHP donde obtienes el codigo de barras, mas que nada puede que sea alli el error, aun que creo que es el tema de pillar el dato de la query.

Comment: anexo el php donde obtengo el código de barras.

Comment: @Carlos solución actualizada

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes utilizar JavaScript, la solución quedaría más u menos así:

```
   <td class="bajo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-16">
      <select style="border:none" class="form-control" name="mod_cve" id="mod_cve">
        <option value="0">-- Selecciona --</option>
        <?php

    $db = new MySQL();  
    $db->open();
    $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM cve ORDER BY name ASC");
    if ($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta)) {
        do {
    echo 
    '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[name].'</option>';
    }while($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta));
    }
                                        ?>
      </select>
      <img id="qr_result" />
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<script>
    document.querySelect('#mod_cve').addEventListener('change', ()=>{
        let selectControl = document.querySelect('#mod_cve');
        let qr_Result = document.querySelect('#qr_result');

        qr_Result.src="codigo_barras/barcode.php?text="+
        selectControl.options[selectControl.selectedIndex].text
        +"&size=40&codetype=Code128&print=true";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @Exodia, gracias por comentar ya coloque tu código pero no me genera ya de plano ningún código de barras.

Comment: me aparece este error con tu corrección Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelect is not a function

Comment: debe ser `document.querySelector()` y no `document.querySelect()`, tuvo un error de dedo.